# Launching Finder in Mac OS X Terminal and highlighting specific files selected from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, finder

I have a script that creates a couple of files in the `/tmp` directory

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/file1.txt
touch /tmp/file2.txt
```

How can I make the script open the `/tmp/` directory in Finder with the two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` selected?

I know I can open the folder with:

```
open /tmp/
```

But it (obviously) doesn’t select the two files.

Comment: @JakeGould Not sure the post-edit title is asking the right thing: I don't want to open files that are already selected in Finder, I want to open Finder with specific files selected.

Comment: No, I think it's clearer now too. It was just the 'for selected files' that was a tad misleading. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the man page for the open(1) command: x-man-page://1/open

There you'll find the `-R` option:

```
-R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them.
```